# URL Rewrite always taking the first condition

Tags: url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule    ^list     lists.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^list/([^-]+)/     lists.php?listid=$1 [NC]
```

The problem is even if the link is like **example.com/list/5** it is directed to list.php without the value. The second condition is not getting satisfied ever. How to solve this?

Comment: very helpful http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^list$     lists.php [L]
RewriteRule ^list/([\d]+)/$     lists.php?listid=$1 [L]
```

Notice that it will match list/5/ but not list/5. That would be:

```
RewriteRule ^list/([\d]+)$     lists.php?listid=$1 [L]
```

Edit: You can use [NC] if you want... I personally like the [L] flag and the case wording respected.